# Error al consumir una API con Node, consulta get

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, axios

Muy buenas, estoy intentando consumir una API con node, el login me lo hace correcto, pero cuando intento llamar a otro controlador para hacer un get, me lanza error de login, pero como os digo si comento es linea de let recipes =.... que es donde llamo al controlador para hacer get, me tira login erroreno.

```
    // AuthController
    var express = require('express');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var axios = require('axios');
    var recipesController = require('./recipesController');
    
    var app = express();
    
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    
    // Muestra el index de la web
    function index(req, res) {
        res.render('index');
    }
    
    // Muestra el index de la web
    function register(req, res) {
        res.render('registro');
    }
    
    // Hacemos login
    function login(req, res) {
        axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'http://localhost:8090/api/auth/login',
                data: {
                    email: req.body.email,
                    password: req.body.password
                }
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                //console.log(response);
                req.session.isLoginCrud = true;
                req.session.userToken = response.data['userToken'];
// Justo estas lineas son las del error, si las comento, me logea perfecto, y me devuelve el token
                let recipes = recipesController.getAllRecipes();
                console.log(recipes);
                res.render('dashboard', {
                    recipes: recipes
                });
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                //console.log(error);
                console.log('llega error');
                res.render('error-login');
            });
    }
    
    // Función para registrar un nuevo usario en la base de datos
    function newRegister(req, res) {
        axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'http://localhost:8090/api/auth/register',
                data: {
                    email: req.body.email,
                    password: req.body.password
                }
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                //console.log(response);
                res.render('exito-registro');
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                res.render('error-registro');
            });
    }
    
    // Exportamos las funciones en un objeto json para poder usarlas en otros fuera de este fichero
    module.exports = {
        index,
        register,
        newRegister,
        login
    };
    
    // RecipesController
    var express = require('express');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var axios = require('axios');
    
    var app = express();
    
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    
    function getAllRecipes() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8090/api/recipes', {
                headers: {
                    'x-access-token': req.session.userToken
                }
            })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error)
            })
    }
    
    // Exportamos las funciones en un objeto json para poder usarlas en otros fuera de este fichero
    module.exports = {
        getAllRecipes
    };
```

Comment: Será porque le faltan los paréntesis a la llamada? => `let recipes = recipesController.getAllRecipes;`

Comment: Lo he probado de las dos formas

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser porque en el getAllRecipes() no devuelves nada y se supone que tiene que devolver algo porque lo encapsulas en una variable.

El catch debería saltar en cualquier previsión de error y si falla ahí, debe ser porque los datos estan llagando mal.

Podrías poner algo así:

```
function getAllRecipes() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8090/api/recipes', {
            headers: {
                'x-access-token': req.session.userToken
            }
        })
        .then((response) => {
            return (response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            return ("error");
        })
}
```

Comment: Pero la pregunta del OP hace referencia a un error de autenticación, no devolución de datos o variables vacías

Comment: Pero en un comentario en el codigo dice que si las comenta le logea y le devuelve el token.

Comment: Si, pero que te devuelva o no datos desde una API, no tiene relación con la generación, inclusión o retorno de un token :D.